# Lists filled with empty data

Tags: c#

Since I'm still a beginner in C# I have some problems with code.
The user is filling out rich text boxes with some questions:

```
List<RichTextBox> boxForQuestions = new List<RichTextBox>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++)
{
       Label labelForEnumeration = new Label();
       labelForEnumeration.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
       labelForEnumeration.Text = labelForEnumeration.Text + ".";
       flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelForEnumeration);

       RichTextBox tempBox = new RichTextBox();
       tempBox.Size = new Size(650,60);
       tempBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,11.0F);
       flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempBox);

       boxForQuestions.Add(tempBox);
}
```

These questions I'm adding to my list of strings:

```
List<string> listOfQuestions = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++)
{
       listOfQuestions.Add(boxForQuestions[i].Text);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to randomize them in some groups in this function:

```
List<List<string>> questions = new List<List<string>>();
static Random rnd = new Random(); 

public void randomizingQuestions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++)
    {
         List<string> groupOfQuestions = new List<string>();
         for (int j = 0; j < numberOfQuestionsPerGroup; j++)
         {
               int index = rnd.Next(listOfQuestions.Count - 1);
               string oneQuestion = listOfQuestions[index];

               foreach (string temp in groupOfQuestions)
               {
                    if (temp != oneQuestion)
                    {
                        groupOfQuestions.Add(oneQuestion);
                    }
               }
         }

         questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
    }
}
```

But, the list is empty because when I want to add these questions to PDF file nothing comes out on the paper:

```
Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 42, 35);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile.FileName, FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

document.Add(new Paragraph("TEST"));

foreach (List<string> question in questions)
{
        document.NewPage();
        foreach (string field in question)
        {
               document.Add(new Paragraph(field));
        }
}

document.Close();
```

Could you tell me what I got wrong?

Comment: What you received in `questions`  while looping over? Try debugging `randomizingQuestions()` method. I guess `groupOfQuestions.Add(oneQuestion);` this line might not be executing, because every time you enter second `for` loop there would be not items in `groupOfQuestions` since you are newing it up. Check from your end if that is what happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, groupOfQuestions is empty at the beginning of the loop so there is no strings in it to enumarate, thus, the statements inside that for-each loop never executes. You could instead use:

```
if(!groupOfQuestions.Contains(oneQuestion)
{
    groupOfQuestions.Add(oneQuestion);
}
```

By the way, if the .Add command had executed, you would get the following exception:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Comment: I now see my mistake but can you explain me your last sentence

Comment: Sure. If you start to iterate on a collection (foreach stetements acrtually call GetEnumaretor() then Next() on the enumerator iinstace and Current to give you the instace (temp in thie case). If you, while using that enumerator, add an item to, or remove an item from that collection, it throws this exception because the enumerator is then obsolete (does not reflect the items of the full collection anymore)

Comment: Do you have any better solution and do you know maybe how can i put numerical order before each string in this list?

Comment: You can use an SortedList<double, string>, and add your strings to the list by sortedList.Add(new Random().NextDouble(), myString). In this case, you sorted list is already randomly distributed.

Comment: Do you think my code is good or should I use yours idea?And what about numerical order before each string?

Comment: You can have a more object oriented approach. I think that way your code will be more readable, and problem domains can be seperated (grouping questions can be one class, while randomizing them another)